# C# Multiple String Contains

Tags: c#

Basically I want to detect more than one string, current code example is

```
if (!str3.Contains("example1"))
{
    continue;
}
```

How would I add " example1 ", " example2 " & " example3 "

Comment: The same way you'd normally test for multiple conditions - join them together with `&&` or `||`. For example: `if (!str3.Contains("example1") && !str3.Contains("example2")...)`

Comment: Detect them all or any one?

Comment: And if you have lots of them you can create an `IEnumerable<T>` such as a `List<T>` and loop through it using appropriate logic to break out of your outer loop.

Comment: Just how many different strings are you talking about here? If they're similar (i.e. "ExampleX"), then regular expression works well. If there are just a few, then cascading ifs, a `switch` statement, or a loop works well. If you have a lot (hundreds) of them, then you need something like the Aho-Corasick algorithm.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Linq` if you want to test with a large list:

```
var excludes = new[] { "example1", "example2", "example3" };

//your loop here
{
    if (!excludes.Any(x => str3.Contains(x)))
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer the way of looping because it solves the problem of manually expanding your code. For example...

```
public void MyMethod(string param)
{
    var myList = new string[] 
    {
        "example1",
        "example2",
        "example3"
    };
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        if (!param.Contains(item)) continue;
    }
    //Do something here
}
```

Basically, you're creating a collection of items you want to search for. Using that, you loop through them and compare them against the target string.

I don't know the full scope of the function so I can't exactly add more but this is already pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

If the strings follow a specific pattern, Regex is always a clean-looking option.

If the strings are "example1", "example2", etc., you could use this regex:

```
/example[0-9]+/g
```

Some C# to find the first and second match (source: http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex):

```
// Get first match.
Match match = Regex.Match(str3, @"example[0-9]+");
if (match.Success)
{
    //matched one of the strings
}

// Get second match.
match = match.NextMatch();
if (match.Success)
{
    //process second match
}
```