# better way to multiple test what contains a string

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently working with culture Info and need to translate some words.
For the days, i use this :

--> input : an `array DayDetails : [MO,TU, WE, TH, FR]` or `[MO, WE,TH,FR,SA]` ...

```
 if ( daysDetails.Length == 7 )
    {
       return langSpec.GetLocalMessage( "every" ) + " " + langSpec.GetLocalMessage( "Days" );
    }
    else if( daysDetails.Length == 5 && daysDetails.Contains( "MO" ) && daysDetails.Contains( "TU" ) && daysDetails.Contains( "WE" ) && daysDetails.Contains( "TH" ) && daysDetails.Contains( "FR" ) )
    {
       return langSpec.GetLocalMessage( "workingDays" );
    }
```

output : a `string` with : Monday, Thuesday, Wednesday

if there's 5 days and it's the working days i want : a `string`with : working days

if there's 7 days i want : a `string`with "every days"

the thing is, i don't like how my second if looks but i have to test, in case of 5 days, that the days are the working days to proper translate it.

Is there a better way to write this, other than multiple && ?

Sorry for my bad english speaking, hope you'll understand.

EDIT : DayDetails can be also [MO,TH], or [MO] or [FR,WE,TH,TU,MO] since it's a response i got from somewhere else and i can't master the input.

EDIT 2 : i checked [Compare two List<T> objects for equality, ignoring order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order) since multiple people suggested it, but it does not really answer to my question. the answer given is way more complicated that my initial "if" with 5 statements.

Comment: Can you show us what is input and what is expected output?

Comment: Why do you *hardcode* don't use `CultureInfo`? E.g. `Console.Write(string.Join(" ", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames));` 
prints out Russian day names (`Вс Пн Вт Ср Чт Пт Сб`)

Comment: Answer is already provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38573437/c-sharp-multiple-string-contains

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two List<T> objects for equality, ignoring order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669970/compare-two-listt-objects-for-equality-ignoring-order)

Comment: Is there any possibility to get, say `{"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"}`?

Comment: @donatasj87 your link is for "OR" but i want "AND"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , not in my input (i don't create the dayDetails, it's just what i receive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array and use All:

```
    private static readonly List<string> workdays = new List<string>() { "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR" };
    private static bool isWorkday(string[] daysDetails) => workdays.All(d => daysDetails.Contains(d));
```

Comment: that's might be what i need. but i can use the "bool" part. It says me that he cannot convert lambda expression to  bool

Comment: nevermind, it was my bad. 

i ended with something like that : 
`else if ( workdays.All( d => daysDetails.Contains( d ) ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` as follows:

```
string[] dayDetails = new [] { "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR" };

if (daysDetails.Length == 7)
{
   return langSpec.GetLocalMessage( "every" ) + " " + langSpec.GetLocalMessage( "Days" );
}
else if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(dayDetails, new [] { "MO", "TU", "WE", "TH", "FR" }))
{
   return langSpec.GetLocalMessage( "workingDays" );
}
```

Assuming `dayDetails` will be in the correct order.